# How to inherit from JQuery ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery, inheritance

I often use ajax request for that kind:

```
$.ajax({
   done : function() {
              alert( "success" );
   },
   fail : fonction() {
              alert( "error" );
   }
})
```

For one of my project I want to create some default action for each ajax request, and I wonder how can I implement it with JavaScript inheritance.

How I would like it looks like:

```
// Definition of the custom and global object in order to override some basic ajax options.
MyCustomAjaxObject = new $.ajax();
MyCustomAjaxObject.error( function () { /* some code for a default */});

// Further in the code, at the moment to trigger one of the ajax request
foo = new MyCustomAjaxObject({
    url : myDestination,
    data : someData
});
```

Do you know if it's possible to use inheritance of that kind with JavaScript?

Comment: Would [`$(document).ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) and [related events](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) be sufficient?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski it could be fine, is there similar way to configure url or dataType ?

Comment: You can use [`jQuery.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) for setting global defaults for (most) `$.ajax()` properties. (It's recommended to use `.ajaxError()`, et al. for event binding.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax()` as it isn't really designed to be used as a constructor, so inheritance probably won't accomplish what you want easily.

You can create a wrapper for it to modify the `options` or resulting `$.Deferred` as desired:

```
// A) default handler
function customAjax(options) {
    if (!options.error) options.error = function () {
        // ...
    };
    return $.ajax(options);
}
```

```
// B) always-in-queue handler
function customAjax(options) {
    return $.ajax(options).error(function () {
        // ...
    });
}
```

And, if you just need to capture ajax events in general, jQuery does include [global event bindings](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/):

```
$(document).ajaxError(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: That's a very good idea. Do you know if it is possible to "save" the `options.error` callback in order to create a new one's, and into it execute the *saved* one. I've edited my question to explain it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your idea was the good one and I succeed in what I was trying to do.